# Copy a file into a subdirectory and rename it

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I'm currently writing a bash file and I'm trying to copy a file into a subdirectory and renaming it to the date and time of modification

I know how to copy it into the subdirectory with

```
cp $1 subdirectory
```

but how do I also rename it to something like 2014-06-28-08-28-59 (years-month-day-hours-minutes-seconds) at the same time?

Thanks!

Edit:

One more question how do I mkdir a directory with a passed in argument?

Like I'm doing

```
./makedirectory directoryname
```

And I want to make a directory with the $1 first argument o_O

Thanks again!

Comment: Do you want to use the current time, the last time the file was modified, etc...

Comment: @user1736436 If you want to make a directory from the command line or a shell script in linux [mkdir](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir) is the tool for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the file name to **2014-06-28-08-28-59** in the subdirectory

```
cp $1 subdirectory/2014-06-28-08-28-59
```

If you want to dynamically set the date to be current, you might want something more like:

```
cp $1 subdirectory/"$(date)"
```

For something relating to the file modification time:

```
cp $1 subdirectory/"$(stat -c %y $1)"
```

If you are wanting to append the information to the original file name:

```
cp $1 subdirectory/"$1--$(stat -c %y $1)"
```

Really this breaks down into:

- If you and to rename a file with `cp` you just provide that file name at the end of the path you want to move it to.
- You can use the returns of a command enclosed in `$( ... )` to extend the functionality any way you want.

Comment: is that supposed to append the date to the filename in the subdirectory?

Comment: No, it will rename the file to the date you want. Are you asking to append to the file name?

Comment: yea is that possible?

Comment: Ooo I see I have a followup question to that so it works flawless in terminal but when I try to write it in the shell script it says missing destination file operand?

Comment: Does stackoverflow notify people who've replied to questions with edits to the original post? o_O

Answer (score 3):

This should copy the file, appending the last time it was modified:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e $1 ]; then
    cp -v $1 subdirectory/$(stat -c %y $1 | awk '{print $1"_"$2}')-${1}
else
    echo "Error: file not found"
fi
exit
```

The if statement checks whether the file exists first.

And this should do the same but append the current time (in a similar format):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e $1 ]; then
    cp -v $1 subdirectory/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)-${1}
else
    echo "Error: file not found"
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

What if we want to place the date/time after the filename and the file has an extension? To handle a file with an extension while preserving the extension, you will need something like this (along with a couple of sanity checks):

```
#!/bin/bash

## copy with date_time, usage:  cpwdt file dir

## test and validate input
test -n "$1" && test -n "$2" || { 
    echo "error: insufficient input, usage: ${0##*/} file dir"
    exit 1
}
test -r "$1" || { echo "error: unable to read '$1'"; exit 1; }
test -w "$2" || { echo "error: insufficient permissions for '$2'"; exit 1; }

## create timestamp (to insure it doesn't change throughout script)
tstamp="$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"

## test target directory existence or create, exit if unable
test -d "$2" || mkdir -p "$2"
test -d "$2" || { echo "error: failed to create '$2'"; exit 1; }

## form filename, test, and copy to destination appending timestamp
basenm="${1%\.*}"
ext="${1##*\.}"

if test "${1}" == "${basenm}" ; then
    fname="${1}_${tstamp}" 
else
    fname="${basenm}_${tstamp}.${ext}"
fi

cp -a "$1" "${2}/${fname}"

exit 0
```

input:

```
$ ls -1 file*
file_no_ext
file_w_ext.txt

$ cpwdt file_no_ext tmp
$ cpwdt file_w_ext.txt tmp
```

output:

```
$ ls -1 tmp
file_no_ext_20140628-221759
file_w_ext_20140628-221819.txt
```

That may provide a bit more flexibility and a few additional checks.